# Problem in finding value field--[my-field-name].tpl.php

Tags: theming, entities

I have a node of product content type,in which a field needs to be alter.I have created a field--[my-field-name].tpl.php and tried to override,my requirement is, field needs to check condition on field value,if condition 1 satisfies then an image will show,else a different image show,but i am unable to find the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

My written code that doesn't work,anything wrong?

```
<div class="meal-type-icon">
<?php
    if($items['field-meal-type'] == "Non Veg"){ ?>
        <img src="../sites/all/themes/freshtopia/images/non-veg.png"/>
<?php } else{ ?>
        <img src="../sites/all/themes/freshtopia/images/veg.jpg"/>
<?php } ?></div>
```

Comment: do you clean the cache?

Comment: Yes I do all the things,but it doesn't work!!